# Waiting for fragment to load with calabash-android

Tags: android, calabash

So in my calabash test script I can call the following macro so that it waits until a certain activity has loaded and is showing:

```
Then I wait up to 10 seconds for the "ActivityName" screen to appear
```

Now my application is heavily based around fragments using this [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library. When I call my new fragments (I haven't used XML files), it's all done in java by creating the new fragment and then switching it like so:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentview_frame, fragment).commit();
```

I know how to write a step definition macro, but I'm looking for the action within this macro that will essentially tell me:

```
Then I wait up to 10 seconds for the "Name" fragment to appear
```

Does anyone think this is possible under the current version of calabash-android?

Answer (score 0):

I think the current version of calabash does have the [macro](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md#waiting) `I wait up to (\d+) seconds to see "([^\"]*)"`, which can be used as following:
    I wait up to 10 seconds to see "text"

`text` being some text in your fragment.

If this is not possible (say, because of localization), then add an id to your fragment, and use the macro `I wait for the view with id "([^\"]*)"`

Comment: Oh ok I see, didn't think of doing that! I'll try when I next get a chance. Thanks